# Getting the error , A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type Form1+LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate::Invoke'

Tags: c#, keyboard, hook

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Windows.Forms;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        using System.Security.Principal;
        using System.Diagnostics;

// The application can disable windows key task manager and ctrl esc etc

        namespace TrialLocks
        {
            public partial class Form1 : Form
            {


                [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "SetWindowsHookExA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
                public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate lpfn, int hMod, int dwThreadId);

                [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "UnhookWindowsHookEx", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
                public static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(int hHook);
                public delegate int LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate(int nCode, int wParam, ref KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam);

                [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "CallNextHookEx", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
                public static extern int CallNextHookEx(int hHook, int nCode, int wParam, ref KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam);
                public const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;

                /*code needed to disable start menu*/
                [DllImport("user32.dll")]
                private static extern int FindWindow(string className, string windowText);
                [DllImport("user32.dll")]
                private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command);


                private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
                private const int SW_SHOW = 1;
                public struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
                {
                    public int vkCode;
                    public int scanCode;
                    public int flags;
                    public int time;
                    public int dwExtraInfo;
                }
                public static int intLLKey;

  // Initialize      
                public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                }
```

// Method to invoke lock keys

```
                public int LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, int wParam, ref KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam)
                {
                    bool blnEat = false;

                    switch (wParam)
                    {
                        case 256:
                        case 257:
                        case 260:
                        case 261:
                            //Alt+Tab, Alt+Esc, Ctrl+Esc, Windows Key,
                            blnEat = ((lParam.vkCode == 9) && (lParam.flags == 32)) | ((lParam.vkCode == 27) && (lParam.flags == 32)) | ((lParam.vkCode == 27) && (lParam.flags == 0)) | ((lParam.vkCode == 91) && (lParam.flags == 1)) | ((lParam.vkCode == 92) && (lParam.flags == 1)) | ((lParam.vkCode == 73) && (lParam.flags == 0));
                            break;
                    }

                    if (blnEat == true)
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, ref lParam);
                    }
                }
```

// Close start menu or windows key

```
                public void KillStartMenu()
                {
                    int hwnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
                    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
                }

// call the form load event and start key board hook

     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
                {

                    intLLKey = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]).ToInt32(), 0);            

                }

// closing the main form

                private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
                {
                    UnhookWindowsHookEx(intLLKey);
                }

                private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    foreach (Process selProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
                    {
                        if (selProcess.ProcessName == "taskmgr")
                        {
                            selProcess.Kill();

                        }
                    }
                }
        // Timer getting started

                private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {            
                      timer1.Start();
                }

    // Timer getting stopped            
    private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    timer1.Stop();            
                }


            }
        }
```

I am Developing an application which cannot be closed by the user interaction.

I am Trying to disable windows keys, task manager etc the application is working fine but when I click on ctrl alt del and focus comes back from lock screen to form1 it crashes with the following error, A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'TrialLocks!TrialLocks.Form1+LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate::Invoke'

The application throws error only when I try to close the Task manager. I think that's where the question is different from the other questions on the same note here.

Any help of guidance would be great.

Comment: it crashes only when the Timer1 event is invoked , if the timer code is removed the rest of the app is working well, I am wondering why the application is crashing because of these ?

Comment: Why don't you just use Windows _kiosk_ mode?

Comment: I cant use it because this can be invoked by user at certain time, at the same time he might be running other apps. All I want is freeze inputs while my app runs, if the user press ctrl alt del and select task manager , it shouldn't be allowed. I don't want to disable task manager by editing Registry, but rather kill the Task manager process.

Comment: Dude, forget this approach, use something like dynamically locking the session or something else, I've been here and I can tell you it's impossible to effectively block input with an application, the user will always find a way to kill your app and execute whatever application wants, through a console, a program which executes an script, a batch file, swapping sessions or any other method.

Comment: @ChikkuJacob Sounds like an utterly terrible design.  Guarenteed to peeve off your users

Comment: This is just for one time use, it should only last max 3 minutes, but during that time I want to have all other inputs frozen

Comment: I am sorry MickyD, need a quick win, so I went for it, Can you advise me a better design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create variable for LowLevelKeyboardProc, otherwise it will be disposed

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate del;
    ...

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        del = new LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate(LowLevelKeyboardProc);
        intLLKey = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, del, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]).ToInt32(), 0);            
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow This works perfect, and that was so quick too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pablo, your are a rockstar mate... Cheers